# One input for two classes

Tags: css, class, input, checked

I use this:

```
#wrap input:checked ~ .topmenu {display: block;}
```

But, how to add another class... Something like:

```
#wrap input:checked ~ .topmenu {display: block;} + .menu-scroll {height: calc(100vh - 60px);}
```

I tried this:

```
#wrap input:checked ~ .toplink {display: block;} 
#wrap input:checked ~ .menu-scroll {height: calc(100vh - 60px);}
```

but second didn't respond.

Is it possible with only css?. Thanx

Comment: Remember to always [tag your question with the language you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) -- [tag:css] in this case. The language tag is the most important tag to use when asking questions; without it, the question is more difficult to find (for those answering & for future viewers).

Comment: Ohh... Sorry this is my first question... I edited and added CSS tag... Thanx,

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm well.. I found answer With A Little Help From My Friends...
The problem was caused by incorrect placing of input element.

This is example solution:

```
<div class="wrapper" id="wrap">
  <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger">
<div class="menu-scroll">
  <label for="hamburger">&#9776;</label>
<div class="toplink"><a href="_toplink1.html">[1] TopLink</a></div>
<div class="toplink"><a href="#link02">[02] DropdownLink</a>
<div class="sublinks" id="link02">
<a href="_sublink_02_1.html">[02] SubLink1</a>
<a href="_sublink_02_2.html">[02] SubLink2</a></div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now this works:

```
#wrap input:checked ~ .menu-scroll .toplink {
  display: block;
}
#wrap input:checked ~ .menu-scroll {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```

Help from [SPC](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/one-input-two-classes/364558/6)